# Sitecore 8.1 index rebuild strategy for SOLR search provider

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

Just read through the index update strategies document below but couldn't get the clear answer on which strategy is best for SOLR search implementation:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/search_and_indexing/index_update_strategies

We have setup the master and slave Solr endpoints where master will be used for create/update. And slave for reading only.

Appreciate if you could suggest the indexing strategy to be used for:

1. Content Authoring
2. Content Delivery

Solution is hosted in azure web apps and content delivery can be scaled up or down from 1-N number at any time.

I'm planning to configure below:

1. Only CA have a OnPublishEndAsync
2. All CDs will not have any indexing strategy.

Appreciate if you could suggest a solution that has worked for you. Also how do we disable indexing strategy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually when you use replication in Solr (master + slave Solr servers), it should be configured like that:

**Content Authoring (CM server)**:

- connects to Solr master server.
- It runs `syncMaster` strategy for `master` database, and `onPublishEndAsync` for `web` database.

**Content Delivery (CD servers)**:

- connects to Solr slave server (or to some load balancer if there are multiple Solr slave servers).
- has all the indexing strategies set to `manual` - they should NEVER update Slave solr servers.

---

With this solution, CD servers always can get results from Solr, even if there is full index rebuild in progress (this happens on `Master` Solr server and data is copied to `Slaves` **after** it's finished).

You should think about having 2 Solr `Slave` servers and load balancer for them. If you do this:

- If Solr `master` is down for some reason, `slaves` still answers to requests from CD boxes. You can safely restart `master`, reindex, and the only thing you lost is that you didn't have 100% up to date search results on CD for some time.
- If one of the Solr `slave` servers is down, second `slave` server still answers to the request and load balancer should redirect all the traffic to the `slave` server which works.

Comment: Awesome awesome answer. Thanks again Marek, appreciate your help again.

Comment: Noticed that there are so many *.web,core,master indexes on content delivery configuration. I guess they ALL need to updated to manual? Otherwise what's the implication?

Comment: I think you're right. But it would be a good idea to contact with Sitecore Support and confirm it.

Comment: Response from support: Hi Anis,
     
Since Solr indexes are usually shared by several Sitecore instances, a particular index should be updated only by one of the instances.
That means that if CM and CDs share the same Solr index (the same Solr core, in fact) like, for example, sitecore_ZZZZZ_web_index, you can set the OnPublishEndAsync strategy for this index on CM and manual strategy - on CDs.
     
Best Regards,
Tamara

Comment: @MarekMusielak  if we set all indexes strategy to manual on CD. Will the 'Clear on Index Update' cache setting still work on CD?

Comment: @NilPun that's a really good question. And to be honest I have no idea. You will have to check this one on your own

Comment: Hi @MarekMusielak  what about analytics index? thanks

Comment: If it's Solr, it's always manual on CD. Only CM or reporting servers update Solr indexes