# Sitecore Web index on CM environment

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am deploying my website on CM and CD environment, i am using solr for search i follow all the instructions from Sitecore to configure cm environment from this link :

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server#_How_to_configure

when i open the cm website, I am getting error says `sitecore_web_index` not found :

[image]

in above link when i go to [Files to enable or disable for Solr](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server#_Files_to_enable_2) section and click on "Excel spreadsheet." they say disable

> Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config :

[image]

Any idea about this error ? should i keep web index disable on CM?

I am using sitecore 8.1 update 2

I am using this code to retrieve items:

```cs
ISearchIndex SitecoreSearchIndex=ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_" + Sitecore.Context.Database.Name + "_index");
using (var context = SitecoreSearchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var culture = Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo;
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
    predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Paths.Contains(CommonTextFolderId));
    predicate = predicate.And(p => p.TemplateId == CommonTextTemplateId);
    predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Language == culture.Name);
    var items = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate);
    listCommonTexts = items.Select(p => SitecoreContext.Cast<CommonTextModel>(p.GetItem(), false, false)).ToList();

}
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace? What tries to use this index?

Comment: @MarekMusielak : I posted the code it is simple search functionality to get list of items.

Answer (score 5):

When using **`Solr`**, you should never disable `sitecore_web_index` on your Content Management server. In fact it's CM server which should rebuild all the indexes.

And on the Content Delivery servers all the indexing strategies should be set to manual - none of the CD servers should rebuild the indexes.

Check this question for explanation what strategy should be used for Solr indexes on both CD and CM servers: [Sitecore 8.1 index rebuild strategy for SOLR search provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082063/sitecore-8-1-index-rebuild-strategy-for-solr-search-provider)