# Sitecore removing documents from Solr

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

We're using Solr (on a Sitecore website) for search and some search-driven pages.  CM is pointing to a sitecore_master_index in Solr, while CD is pointing to a sitecore_web_index.  We're using the OnPublishEndAsync strategy.  Something really odd is happening.

When we publish content, it shows up on CD (and the correct Solr index), then, about 90 seconds later, it's gone.

If anybody has any insight into why this might happen, please let me know.

I've enabled all of the "Update" logs in solr, and I don't see any records deleting my item.  Please let me know if that's not the right place.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 CM server?

Comment: I don't, no.  Thanks.

Comment: Do your CD server have all the indexing strategies set to "manual"?

Comment: It does not.  The CD server is set to onPublishEndAsync for the Web index.  My understanding is that's the ways it's supposed to be configured.

Comment: No. Only CM server writes to indexes. CD server only reads from them. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082063/sitecore-8-1-index-rebuild-strategy-for-solr-search-provider

Comment: That would have been my assumption, but this doc (and other's like it) https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/configure_a_search_and_indexing_provider suggests otherwise.  There's a spreadsheet referenced about halfway through the page that specifies configuring the WEB db on CD servers, and not on the CM servers.  Our configuration (right now) does not have a master/slave setup.  There's just one Solr server.

Comment: Try configuring Solr as I described and check if this works for you. And contact your Sitecore office for confirmation. This sounds incorrect. CD server should not use master index and use web indexes instead, but only in read only mode.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Index strategy for sitecore_master_index is **syncMaster** and for sitecore_web_index should be **onPublishEndAsync**

**1) Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config:**

```
<strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster" />
        </strategies>
```

**2) Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config:**

```
<strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
            </strategies>
```

Comment: I checked.  This is the case.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  This is already the case.  This is they way it's been configured, and it's still breaking.